# Using Lego temperature sensor with Arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c

I have Arduino mega and Lego temperature sensor which I would like to connect to the Arduino. I'm trying to use a I2C connection between them, with no luck. I connected the sensor and Arduino referring to the picture below:[image: wiring]
I'm using the Wire library for transmitting data. This is my code currently:

```
#include < Wire.h >
byte ADDRESS=0x98;
byte CONFIG=0x01;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(CONFIG);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(100);
}
void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(CONFIG);
 Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS,2);
  delay(100);
  int avail=Wire.available();
  Serial.println(avail);
  delay(100);
}
```

I found the config and address values from [RobotC drivers](https://github.com/botbench/robotcdriversuite/blob/master/include/lego-temp.h) for the same sensor. But all I get is zeros. Is there any way i could check for a defect sensor? Is my code correct?

Comment: Start with a i2c scanner : http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner

Comment: Looks like this is the datasheet for the actual sensor http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp275.pdf. Reading that and cross referencing with the header file you liked to, should explain how to communicate with it.

Comment: I2C scanner helped me to use the correct address, which was different from the one in drivers. Now my sensor is working. Thank you, Jot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it work with the following code:

```
float getTemp(){
    #define ADDRESS 0x4C
    #define CONFIG 0x00
    float temp;
    Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS);
    Wire.write(CONFIG);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(50);
    Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS,2);
    temp=Wire.read();
    if(Wire.read()==128){
        temp+=0.5;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And connect the green wire to 3.3V, not to the 5V.